# What characters should be escaped in a Bracket Expression '[...]'?

Tags: bash, regular-expression

With the following regex `[{-]` it does not seem that the `{` needs to be escaped.  Is this correct? And what other characters doesn't/does required to be escaped within Bracket Expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there are dozens of different regexp flavours. The POSIX standard specifies at least 4 (BRE, ERE, awk EREs, `ex`/`vi` BRE), and there are many more like those of `perl`, PCRE, `vim`, `ksh93` etc.

In [POSIX BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (as used by `grep`/`sed`) and [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (as used by `grep -E`/`sed -E` or `bash`'s `[[ =~ ]]`¹), inside [bracket expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) (`[...]`), the only characters that are special are `^` (when first),  `]` (when not first or following `]`), `-` (when not first nor last or following `^`) and `[` when part of some `[.x.]`, `[:class:]`, `[=e=]`... Newline, even if not special in itself in the regex syntax is often special in utilities that use regexp such as `grep` where it separates regexps.

`\` in those is meant not to be special and in theory cannot be used to escape characters or used in things like `\t` to specify a TAB.

`[\-~]` is meant to match on a range of characters from `\` to `~`. To match on either `-` or `~`, it's `[~-]` or `[-~]`. Remember `-` needs to be first or last, `]` needs to be first, and `[` should not be followed by a `.`, `=` or `:`.

`{` in any case is not special, `-` is, but not when in last position like you did.

Note that while `[\t]` and `[t\]` are required to match on either `\` or `t` in BRE and ERE, I would not rely on it, as there are several utilities that ignore that requirement. Use `[\\t]` or `[\\t]` to match on either `\` or `t`.

For instance, in GNU `sed`, `sed 's/[\t]//'` removes TABs instead of `\` and `t` unless `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in its environment.

---

<sup>¹ anecdotally, `bash`'s `[[ '\' =~ ['.'] ]]` used to return true, as seeing the quoted `.`, it would call the regexp engine with `[\.]` as the regex in an attempt to escape the dot which here doesn't need escaping, and 4.4 still fails to return true on `[[ '\' =~ [^]'.'] ]]` for the same reason.</sup>